# Error is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: while invoking weservice

Tags: java, web-services

I am getting this Error is java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: exception while invoking the web service url that i have.

I am calling a .NET based web service through a framework built in java and getting:

Headers returned from the server:

```
Content-Length:736
Content-Type:text/xml; charset=utf-8
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.0
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
Date:Thu, 12 May 2011 08:51:45 GMT

java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 500 for URL: "http://hcd
cd-bt01.hcch.com/HCCExceptionLogService/service.svc?wsdl"
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLCon
nection.java:1170)
        at com.splwg.mpl.senders.http.HTTPSender.sendResponse(HTTPSender.java:34
5)
        at com.splwg.mpl.sending.NewSenderManager.sendResponse(NewSenderManager.
java:191)
        at com.splwg.mpl.sending.SameThreadSendingManager.callSender(SameThreadS
endingManager.java:63)
        at com.splwg.mpl.stagingtable.download.OutboundMessageSender.handleRouti
ngs(OutboundMessageSender.java:361)
        at com.splwg.mpl.stagingtable.download.OutboundMessageSender.sendRespons
e(OutboundMessageSender.java:95)
        at com.splwg.mpl.sending.NewSenderManager.sendResponse(NewSenderManager.
java:191)
        at com.splwg.mpl.sending.SameThreadSendingManager.processDestination(Sam
eThreadSendingManager.java:293)
        at com.splwg.mpl.sending.SameThreadSendingManager.sendResponse(SameThrea
dSendingManager.java:252)
        at com.splwg.mpl.sending.SameThreadSendingManager.doSend(SameThreadSendi
ngManager.java:208)
        at com.splwg.mpl.server.async.ExecSendRequestProcessor.ProcessRequest(Ex
ecSendRequestProcessor.java:61)
        at com.splwg.mpl.server.async.RequestProcessingThreadAdapter.run(Request
ProcessingThreadAdapter.java:46)
        at com.splwg.mpl.server.PooledThread.run(PooledThread.java:91)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
```

The wsdl url which i am invoking is `http://hcdcdbt01.hcch.com/HCCExceptionLogService/service.svc?wsdl`

I have used SOAP UI 3.6.1 tool for testing this wsdl which is giving me the right result.

Headers that i have used are:

```
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IExceptionLogService/LogException"
POST
Host:hcdcd-bt01.hcch.com
http://hcdcd-bt01.hcch.com/HCCExceptionLogService/service.svc
```

SOAP UI HEADERS:

```
POST http://hcdcd-bt01.hcch.com/HCCExceptionLogService/service.svc HTTP/1.1
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/IExceptionLogService/LogException"
User-Agent: Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1
Host: hcdcd-bt01.hcch.com
Content-Length: 763
```

Can any body tell me what went wrong ?

Comment: Unanswerable without the server logs.

Answer (score 1):

It is a server error response, presumably on an internal service as the given address doesn't reside on the internet AFAIK.
You must get the server logs to establish what it does not like about your request.

Answer (score 0):

Since the server sent the response code 500 - internal server error - I think you'll have to debug it on the server side, not the client side.

You should check the output of the server log.